# How to count/sum the total rows of records in tree view of wizard in odoo 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, treeview, odoo-10, wizard

I am struggling now on how to compute the total rows or records in my tree view on wizard.

I have a button "on hand" in my form view, and inside my on hand button is a wizard, if you click the button it will trigger a wizard that has a record on it.

All i want is, in my "on hand" button, i want to display the total number of records inside of that button.

Many thanks.

This is my form view that has a button on hand.

[image: This is my form view that has a button on hand]

and this is wizard containing record inside that button.

[image: my wizard]

In picture, I have two records, and I want to display it in my on hand button.

Comment: precalculate it and add into the button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a field function to count total list in a record, example like this.

```
@api.multi 
def _get_count_list(self):
        data_obj    = self.env['example.object']
        for data in self:       
               list_data        = data_obj.search([('Fill the condition')])
               data.example_count = len(list_data)
```

example_count      = fields.Integer("Count", compute='_get_count_list')

Comment: you save me. Thank you :) Big help.